# Which maps and locations are these operator art images from?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege, arknights

Apparently a Rainbow 6 banner is coming soon to Arknights with 4 new operators. Having played Rainbow 6 in the past some of the locations that are shown here are familiar to me and the others are not so familiar.  Hoping to get an exact clarification of which sites specifically these are supposed to be based off?

> It's Yacht, but I don't know which floor it is. With all the electronics it kind of reminds me of the basement level.
> [image]

> Appears to be Kafe Dostoyevsky, the 2nd floor bookcase room I believe?
> [image]

> This one is the most obvious but I could still be very wrong, it appears to be the Clubhouse 1st floor bar
> [image]

> Not sure of this one entirely. Looks like it could be Hereford, Embassy, Bank, or any other map with a darker theme
> [image]

> This one I think is Kafe, 3rd floor, piano room?
> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like after doing some digging they seem to match up exactly to their appropriate locations.

#### Tachanka Elite 2 art

- Kafe map, 2F, Reading Room
- [image]

#### Blitz Elite 2 art

- Clubhouse map, 1F, Bar
- [image]

#### Frost Elite 2 art

- Yacht map, unknown
- No room in Yacht has a pillar with two barricaded windows to either side. The reason this is not Tower is because of the art image on the pillar which depicts the Yacht.
- Does not seem to have a real in-game location unlike the other ops

#### Ash Elite 2 art

- Oregon map, 1F, Rear Stage
- For whatever reason the art is a mirrored version of how it actually appears in-game
- [image]

#### Tachanka Lord skin art

- Kafe map, 3F, Piano Room
- [image]

Answer (score 0):

I do think your guesses are pretty on point, but where it falls apart is that you try to 100% put the image like its a screenshot of RB6.

But I guess its more 'heavily inspired by, but took liberties'.

So thats why you can take a guess about the maps/locations of that art, but its not a 100% match with the map.